# Reducing/Filtering a HashMap<String, List> collection using Java streams API

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the ff. data set

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> oldNumList
```

containing a data like

```
"odd": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
"even": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

I'd like to transform the data into

```
"odd": 9 // greatest odd num of the odd list
"even": 10 // greatest even num of the even list
```

so the resulting type would become

```
Map<String, Integer>
```

my solution so far was to do something like this

```
Map<String, Integer> numList = new HashMap<>();
numList.put("odd", oldNumList.get("odd").stream()
      .mapToInt(v -> v)
      .max());
numList.put("even", oldNumList.get("even").stream()
      .mapToInt(v -> v)
      .max());
```

I was looking into a more compact solution i.e. not to declare a new HashMap variable

Comment: @Naman updated to include my initial solution, but i want something more compact, i.e. not to declare a new HashMap variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stream :

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> Collections.max(e.getValue())));
```

and [Collections max(Collection coll)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-)

> Returns the maximum element of the given collection, according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the collection must implement the Comparable interface.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I'm actually working with ```Map<String, List<Object>>```, that part I'll have to figure out on my own.

Comment: @VinceJeraldVillamora look for `Collectors.maxBy` example and its documentation, would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Collectors.groupingBy** along with **Collectors.reducing** first to group by keys and use reduce to transform each map values which are lists to the maximum

```
Map<String, Object> collect = map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                Collectors.reducing(Function.identity(),
                        e -> e.getValue().stream().reduce(Integer::max).get(),
                        (i1, i2) -> i2)));
```